# How to tell if my functions requires more cpu speed

Tags: google-cloud-functions

From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation), I can increase the cpu speed by increasing the function memory.

Is there a way where I can measure if my function require more cpu speed (Hz)?

Comment: Not directly. Add more memory and see if the function finish faster. Keep in mind that is your function finish 2 time earlier with 2 time more CPU, it will cost 2 time more over 2 time less duration. (Not sure that my english is understandable, but the key takeaway is: increase CPU/Memory if you have time constraint)

Comment: To help clarify: a 2x CPU generally costs more like 3x the price/second - the process will finish in half the time, but it will cost you 1.5x the price. It is *generally* less expensive to use a slower CPU for a longer period - UNLESS you have a particularly large amount of processing and are timing out - which is unusual,

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the console, there are "details" pages for the functions that will show you both time & memory statistics, so you can see directly how your function is performing.  As I mentioned above, a 2x CPU generally costs more like 3x the price/second - the process will finish in half the time, but it will cost you 1.5x the price. It is *generally* less expensive to use a slower CPU for a longer period - UNLESS you have a particularly large amount of processing and are timing out - which is unusual.